# Is the hadith regarding Dajjal (the anti-christ) on a sail boat authentic?

Tags: hadith, dajjal

I have got a different information about [Dajjal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Al-Masih_ad-Dajjal) (the anti-christ). When I read it, it feel like he is still alive. The following is the information I got from [AhmadJibril](http://ahmadjibril.com/students/signs.html) website.

> A Sahabi meets Dajjal:
>   Fatima bint Qais said that she heard the voice of an announcer making an announcement that the prayer would be observed in the mosque (where) congregational prayer (is observed). So she set out towards the mosque and observed prayer with the Allah's Apostle (peace be upon him) and she was in the row of the women which was near the row of men.
>
> When Allah's Apostle (peace be upon him) had finished his prayer, he sat on the pulpit, smiling, and said: Every worshipper should remain sitting in his place. He then said: Do you know why I have asked you to assemble? They said: Allah and His apostle know best. He said: By Allah, I have not made you assemble for exhortation or for a warning. I have detained you here because Tamim Dari, a Christian who came and accepted Islam, told me something which agrees with what I was telling you about the Dajjal. He narrated to me that he had sailed in a ship with thirty men of Banu Lakhm and Banu Judham and had been tossed by waves in the ocean for a month. Then these (waves) took them (near) the land within the ocean (island) at the time of sunset.
>
> They sat in a small rowing-boat and landed on that island. There was a beast with long thick hair (and because of this) they could not distinguish his face from his back. They said:
>
> - Woe to you, who can you be?
>
>   Thereupon it said: I am al-Jassasah.
>
>   They said: What is al-Jassasah?
>
>   It said: You go to this very person in the monastery for he is eagerly waiting for you to know about you. So we came to you in hot haste fearing that that might be the Devil.
>
>   He (that chained person) said: Tell me about the date-palm trees of Baysan.
>
>   We said: In which respect do you seek information about it?
>
>   He said: I ask you whether these trees bear fruit or not.
>
>   We said: Yes.
>
>   Thereupon he said: I think these will not bear fruit.
>
>   He said: Inform me about the lake of Tabariyyah?
>
>   We said: What do you want to know about it?
>
>   He said: Is there water in it?
>
>   They said: There is an abundance of water in it. Thereupon he said: I think it will soon dry up.
>
>   He again said: Inform me about the spring of Zughar.
>
>   They said: What do you want to know about it?
>
>   He (the chained person) said: Is there water in it and does it irrigate (the land)?
>
>   We said to him: Yes, there is an abundance of water in it and the inhabitants (of Medina) irrigate (land) with its help.
>
>   He said: Inform me about the unlettered Prophet; what has he done?
>
>   We said: He has left Mecca and has settled in Yathrib (Medina).
>
>   He said: Do the Arabs fight against him?
>
>   We said: Yes. He said: How does he deal with him?
>
>   We informed him that he had overcome those in his neighborhood and they had submitted themselves before him.
>
>   Thereupon he said to us: Had it actually happened?
>
>   We said: Yes.
>
>   Thereupon he said: If it is so that is better for them that they show obedience to him. I am going to tell you about myself. I am the Dajjal and will be soon permitted to leave. So I shall leave and travel in the land, and shall not spare any town where I shall not stay for forty nights except Mecca and Medina: these two (places) are prohibited (areas) for me and I shall not attempt to enter either of them. An angel with a sword in his hand will confront me and bar my way and there will be angels to guard every road leading to it.
>     Then Allah's apostle (peace be upon him) striking the pulpit with the help of the end of his staff said: This implies Tayba meaning Medina.
>
>   Have I not told you an account (of the Dajjal) like this?
>
>   The people said: Yes, and this account narrated by Tamim Dari was liked by me for it corroborates the account which I gave to you in regard to him (Dajjal) at Medina and Mecca.
>     Behold he (Dajjal) is in the Syrian sea (Mediterranean) or the Yemen sea (Arabian sea). Nay, on the contrary, he is in the east, he is in the east, he is in the east, and he pointed with his hand towards the east.

**I haven't heard about this information. Is it related to any Hadith, if yes then which hadith**

Comment: The way the hadith was reported, it's not clear whether the event was real or if Tamim ad-Dari had a dream and told it to the Prophet.  But the Prophet never confirmed or denied it.  So Allah knows better about its reality.

Comment: This is apparently a hadith mentioned in sahih Muslim as @Hamid mentioned in his answer http://sunnah.com/muslim/54/149

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is from an authentic hadith, e.g. [Jami` at-Tirmidhi 2253](http://sunnah.com/tirmidhi/33/96).

Comment: I wonder why this was accepted as an answer as on the other hand an a similar answer with an indication of an other source of the hadith was down voted!

Answer (score 2):

> Fatimah bint Qais narrated that Allah's Prophet(s.a.w) ascended the Minbar, he laughed, and said:
>   "Verily, Tamim Ad-Dari narrated a story to me, and it made me happy, so I wanted to narrate it to you[what he narrated to me]. Some people among the inhabitants of Palestine traveled by boat in the sea, taking them here and there, until it cast them on an island among the islands at sea. There they found a beast, clothed with its hair flowing out. They said: 'What are you?' It said: 'I am Al-Jassasah.' They said: 'Give us some news.' It said: 'I shall not give you any news, nor do I want any of your news. But go to the furthest village, for there is someone who will give you news and seek your news.' So we went to the furthest village, and there was a man fettered with chains. He said: 'Inform me about the spring of Zughar.' We said: '   It is full and flowing.' He said: 'Inform me about Al-Buhairah.' We said,'It is full and flowing.' He said: 'Inform me about the date groves of Baysan which is between Jordan and Palestine, do they produce food?' We said: 'Yes.' He said: 'Inform me about the Prophet, has he been sent?' We said: 'Yes.' He said: 'Inform me how the people came to him.' We said: 'Quickly.' He leaped up to try and escape.' We said: 'What are you?' **He said: 'I am the Dajjal.**'" (The Prophet(s.a.w) said) "He will enter all of the lands except At-Taibah, and At-Taibah is Al-Madinah."

Tirmidhi 7/2253

Sahih (Darussalam)

http://muflihun.com/hadith/6/7/2253

Answer (score -1):

this hadith is in Muslim hadith no. 7028.

Comment: I recommend you to read http://islam.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer

Answer (score -2):

Narrated by Fatimah Daughter of Qays & sister of ad-Dahhak Ibn Qays

Amir ibn Sharahil ash-Sha’bi said: Fatimah bint Qays was among the first emigrant women. I asked her to narrate to me a hadith which she had heard directly from Allah’s Apostle (peace be upon him) and there was no extra link between them. She said: Very well, if you like, I am prepared to do that. He said to her: Well, do so and narrate it to me. She said: I married the son of Mughirah and he was a chosen young man of Quraysh at that time, but he fell as a martyr in the first Jihad (fighting on the side of Allah’s Apostle (peace be upon him)). When I became a widow, AbdurRahman ibn Awf, one of the group of the companions of Allah’s Apostle. sent me a proposal of marriage. Allah’s Apostle (peace be upon him) also sent me such a message for his freed slave, Usamah ibn Zayd. It had been conveyed to me that Allah’s Apostle (peace be upon him) had said (about Usamah): He who loves me should also love Usamah. When Allah’s Apostle (peace be upon him) talked to me (about this matter), I said: My affairs are in your hands. You may marry me to anyone you wish. He said: You had better move now to the house of Umm Sharik. Umm Sharik was a rich lady from among the Ansar. She spent generously for the cause of Allah and entertained guests very hospitably. I said: Well, I shall do as you wish. He said: Do not do that because Umm Sharik is a woman who is very frequently visited by guests and I do not like your head to be uncovered or removed from your shank and the strangers may catch sight of that which you abhor. You had better move to the house of your cousin, Abdullah ibn Amr ibn Umm Maktum. He was one of the Banu Fihr branch of the Quraysh, and he belonged to that tribe (to which Fatimah) belonged. So I moved to that house, and when my period of waiting was over, I heard the voice of an announcer making an announcement that the prayer would be observed in the mosque (where) congregational prayer (is observed). So I set out towards the mosque and observed prayer with the Allah’s Apostle (peace be upon him) and I was in the row of the women which was near the row of men. When Allah’s Apostle (peace be upon him) had finished his prayer, he sat on the pulpit, smiling, and said: Every worshipper should remain sitting in his place. He then said: Do you know why I have asked you to assemble? They said: Allah and His apostle know best. He said: By Allah, I have not made you assemble for exhortation or for a warning. I have detained you here because Tamim Dari, a Christian who came and accepted Islam, told me something which agrees with what I was telling you about the Dajjal. He narrated to me that he had sailed in a ship with thirty men of Banu Lakhm and Banu Judham and had been tossed by waves in the ocean for a month. Then these (waves) took them (near) the land within the ocean (island) at the time of sunset. They sat in a small rowing-boat and landed on that island. There was a beast with long thick hair (and because of this) they could not distinguish his face from his back. They said: Woe to you, who can you be? Thereupon it said: I am al-Jassasah. They said: What is al-Jassasah? It said: O people, go to this person in the monastery as he is very much eager to know about you. He (the narrator) said: When it named a person for us we were afraid of it lest it should be a Devil. Then we hurried on till we came to that monastery and found a well-built person there with his hands tied to his neck and iron shackles gripping his legs by the ankles. We said: Woe to you, who are you? He said: You soon come to know about me, but tell me who you are. We said: We are people from Arabia and we embarked upon a boat but the waves had been driving us for one month and they brought us near this island. We took to the rowing-boats and landed on this island. Here a beast with profusely thick hair met us and because of the thickness of his hair his face could not be distinguished from his back. We said: Woe be to thee, who are you? It said: I am al- Jassasah. We said: What is al-Jassasah? It said: You go to this very person in the monastery for he is eagerly waiting for you to know about you. So we came to you in hot haste fearing that that might be the Devil. He (that chained person) said: Tell me about the date-palm trees of Baysan. We said: In which respect do you seek information about it? He said: I ask you whether these trees bear fruit or not. We said: Yes. Thereupon he said: I think these will not bear fruit. He said: Inform me about the lake of Tabariyyah? We said: What do you want to know about it? He said: Is there water in it? They said: There is an abundance of water in it. Thereupon he said: I think it will soon dry up. He again said: Inform me about the spring of Zughar. They said: What do you want to know about it? He (the chained person) said: Is there water in it and does it irrigate (the land)? We said to him: Yes, there is an abundance of water in it and the inhabitants (of Medina) irrigate (land) with its help. He said: Inform me about the unlettered Prophet; what has he done? We said: He has left Mecca and has settled in Yathrib (Medina). He said: Do the Arabs fight against him? We said: Yes. He said: How does he deal with him? We informed him that he had overcome those in his neighbourhood and they had submitted themselves before him. Thereupon he said to us: Had it actually happened? We said: Yes. Thereupon he said: If it is so that is better for them that they show obedience to him. I am going to tell you about myself. I am the Dajjal and will be soon permitted to leave. So I shall leave and travel in the land, and shall not spare any town where I shall not stay for forty nights except Mecca and Medina: these two (places) are prohibited (areas) for me and I shall not attempt to enter either of them. An angel with a sword in his hand will confront me and bar my way and there will be angels to guard every road leading to it. Then Allah’s apostle (peace be upon him) striking the pulpit with the help of the end of his staff said: This implies Tayba meaning Medina. Have I not told you an account (of the Dajjal) like this? The people said: Yes, and this account narrated by Tamim Dari was liked by me for it corroborates the account which I gave to you in regard to him (Dajjal) at Medina and Mecca. Behold he (Dajjal) is in the Syrian sea (Mediterranean) or the Yemen sea (Arabian sea). Nay, on the contrary, he is in the east, he is in the east, he is in the east, and he pointed with his hand towards the east. I (Fatimah bint Qays) said: I preserved it in my mind (this narration from Allah’s Messenger (peace be upon him).

Hadith7028 (Sahih Muslim Hadith)

Comment: This is copy/pasted from http://www.templemount.org/islameschat.html  Look under "Book 40, Number 7028".